# Table with tabular, column type p grabbing available space

Tags: tables

I have a table with one column which contains a longer description spanning multiple lines. Therefore I use the column type `p`, which requires me to specify a fixed column width. Is it possible to specify the column in such a way, that the table column simply "grabs" all available horizontal space?

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    % I would like to avoid hard coding the column width here
    \begin{tabular}{l p{5cm}}
        column 1 & column 2 \\
        name & The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [tabularx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
...

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
...
\end{tabularx}
```

Column type `X` provides what you need.